# Direction issue In Numeric text English to Arabic

Tags: android, android-layout, arabic-support

I am developing android application with supporting **Arabic** & **English** Language

For the Arabic language i was followed below steps :

> - Android Studio > Refactor > Add RTL support where possible…
> - 2nd I'll paste this line in `manifest.xml` : `android:supportsRtl="true"`

**or**

> - I was changed layout property `Left` and `Right` **with** `Start` and `End`

---

Wow I'm happy after this changes because when i select **Arabic** Language some design is going to **`LTR`** but when i test my application i found some issues.

For example see below image :

[image]

When i set RTL
You can see birthday(15/05/1994) is shown as `LTR` and all text shown as  `RTL`(DOB,Gender,City).

Here is a problem birthday is show as 'LTR'  then **WHY** other EditText is not going to **`RTL`**.

Here you can see my code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_age"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dob"
        android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size" />

    <EditText
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/edit_dob"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="15/05/1994"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size" />
</RelativeLayout><include layout="@layout/half_view" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_gender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gender"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_gender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_gender"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="Male"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
    android:background="@null"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout><include layout="@layout/half_view" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/city"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_city"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Patan"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
    android:background="@null"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

- I already read this [official](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) page but didn't helpful for me.

Comment: It is issue of relative layout. Try with linear layout.

Comment: i also try in `LinearLayout` @DharaJani

Comment: Why there are still english, have you not set arabic strings?

Comment: yes hear not set arabic language i just move `ENG` then `LTR` and `Arabic` then `RTL`@VaradMondkar

Comment: remove gravity from edittext

Comment: Even I am developing android app with Arabic support. Here when translate all english strings to arabic in strings.xml(ar) then it gives me proper `rtl` layout

Comment: bro i check everything you can see my design properly. if all hint are come `LTR` to `RTL` and DOB is `RTL` to `LTR` then why other fields not move ?? @VaradMondkar

Comment: @MohammadAli remove Gravity and align_parentEnd = ture from edittext

Comment: @MohammadAli I said remove it. is set layout at end of its parent layout and its parent relative layout have width match parent so its will show at end of  its layout.

Comment: sry for that but i need it becoz i want to show hint in Left side and Data show in `Right` side that's why i'm using this line :)@VishalThakkar

Comment: @MohammadAli  try i have posted answer.

Comment: @VaradMondkar who me?

Comment: @VishalThakkar No my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

In RTL when you have set text as numeric this things happen.

LayoutDirection property added from API 19 please check [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection)

Add below property to Edittext.

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

**RTL ScreenShot**

[image: RTL ScreenShot]

**LTR Screenshot**

[image: LTR Screenshot]

For more info check this [reference For RTL support](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

Comment: i already follow this link and i used your given line code but didn't work

Comment: @MohammadAli i was just checked in preview

Comment: wait wait can you please check your `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @MohammadAli i was checked in emulator also ans posted screenshot

Comment: @MohammadAli its 21

Comment: and i can use 16 it is okay or i want to change it ??

Comment: this property is for 4.2+ so it will not work in API 16 you have to create Version wise layout if you want to give support.

Comment: okay it's show me same like your 1st image but why mail and Patan String are not going to end of layout ?? When **RTL**

Comment: @MohammadAli because its text just set text as number and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178859/discussion-between-vishal-thakkar-and-mohammad-ali).